# Save AWK output operation inside variable and use the variable after another bash command

Tags: shell, variables, awk, output

My source files:

**0.txt:**

```
anything1
anything2
anything3
anything4
```

**1.txt** as bellow:

```
house();
shop("");
house();
shop("");
house();
shop("");
```

when using:

```
awk \
'FNR==1 {++f}
f==1 {a[i++]=$0}
f==2 {if ($0~/house/) {gsub(/house/, a[int(j++/2)%2]) }; print > "a.txt"}
' \
0.txt 1.txt
```

so a.txt:

```
anything1();
shop("");
anything1();
shop("");
anything2();
shop("");
```

But I would like to pass this *content* first to a `variable` and then use this `variable` to write on `a.txt` using `system()`:

```
awk -v myvar='' \
'FNR==1 {++f}
f==1 {a[i++]=$0}
f==2 {if ($0~/house/) {gsub(/house/, a[int(j++/2)%2]) }; print > $myvar; system("touch $myvar a.txt")}
' \
0.txt 1.txt
```

This print files with names `anything1();`, `anything2();`, `anything1();` ..

*but print* `a.txt` empty.

It is possible to capture the output of `f==2` (current file being processed in `FNR==1 {++f}`) to the `myvar` variable and then pass to `system()`?

Comment: Maybe you should simplify your example code. It is unclear why you want to store the data in variables and how you want to process the variables later. As far as I can see, your script creates files `a.txt` and `b.txt`. Do you want to process the data in these files? The code `cat $f | grep 'house'` would extract lines that match `house` from a file which is named as the value of `$f`. It would do the same as `grep ' house' $f`.  What is your expected final result? It might be difficult to set shell variables as you think you want to. Why not directly do all processing in a single AWK script?

Comment: @Bodo Sample: All output from `sub(/shop[[:space:]]*\(".*"\)/,"shop(\""a[int(x1%(54*2)/1)+0]"\")")) {x1++}; if (sub(/house[[:space:]]*\(.*\)/,"house("a[int(x2%(54*2)/1)+0]")")) {x2++} ` should be stored in the `$h` variable, and then used in  `cat $h | grep 'house'`. I am afraid that if I use a simple example does not work with the others owned from my actual AWK command, but I will try to update the question with an example less

Comment: @Bodo Really process the variables inside the `AWK` can be a simple alternative in case using `system ("cat $h  | grep 'house'")`? I'll try to try to do this and some tests.

Comment: @Bodo Yes `$h` exercises the same function as `a.txt`.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add information/clarification instead of using comments for this purpose. It is still unclear **why** you want variables. Now it's even less clear if you want a shell variable or an AWK variable. Using `system` in an AWK script should be avoided if possible. Probably it can be implemented in AWK. The purpose of your example `system` command is unclear. It will update the files' timestamps or create empty files.  `cat $h` expects that the shell variable `h` contains *a file name* and will type this file. `cat file | grep pattern` is the same as `grep pattern file`

Answer (score 0):

```
awk 'FNR==1 {++f; if(f>2) print ""}
     f==1   {a[NR]=$0; next}
     f==2 &&   FNR%2  {sub(/\(\)/,"(" a[int(FNR/2)+1] ")"); print}
     f==3 && !(FNR%2) {sub(/\(""\)/,"(\"" a[FNR/2+1] "\")"); print}' file1 file2 file3

house(anything1);
house(anything2);
house(anything3);

shop("anything2");
shop("anything3");
shop("anything4");
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, but I still can not see how I would create a variable and would use it out of `AWK` from your response. I do not quite understand your example, apparently it just reproduces the output desires but I do not see variables in it and also do not see `cat` or `grep` command. Sorry my ignorance.

Comment: whole purpose was to eliminate the variables and there is no need for cat or grep since all can be done in one awk script.

Comment: My question is a micro example of my real need, the solution to this issue solves my real macro need. But for all purposes it is necessary to create the cited variables and the possibility of being able to use them. So the source files and the presented outputs in my post are small but cover the necessary and sufficient characteristics, but this does not mean that I just want to reproduce the expected outputs of new ways, what I want is the creation of the variables (as I mentioned ) and the possibility of using them

Comment: @7beggars_nnnnm Please edit your question instead of using comments to add information. Please add background information **why** you think you need variables. What is your *real macro need*? Please describe the As I already wrote, it is difficult to create more than one shell variable from AWK output. There is probably a better solution.